# Generating single .so from multiple C++ and C object files

Tags: c++, c, linker, dynamic-linking

Let's say I have a C++ library code, with some definitions wrapped with `extern "C" { ... }`.

I also have a C library code which uses that C++ library.

What I want to do is to create a single .so file, so that only one call to `dlopen` should be enough to start using this library.

Here's what I do now: I'm first compiling my C++ library to a .so file with `-shared -rdynamic -fPIC`. Then I'm compiling my C library to a .so file with same parameters. After that, I have to load C++ library with `dload` before loading the C library. Otherwise loading fails with a `undefined symbol` error.

What I want to do is to compile this two libraries into one .so file so that only one call to `dload` should be enough to use it.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Compiling to .o files and then combining doesn't work for me. Here's what I do:

- I compile each file to object file with -fPIC parameter
- I link them with `clang [list of object files] -shared -rdynamic -fPIC -o libmylib.so`
- When I try to load, I get `undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0` error.

EDIT2: Ahh, I forgoto to link it against `libstdc++`, it works now. Thanks.

Comment: Just stick all the object files as arguments to the linking line?

Comment: @MatsPetersson, for some reason, that doesn't work. should I use any additional parameters while compiling to object files?

Comment: @sinan Are these unresolved symbols? If yes, you need to link them in a specific order. http://stackoverflow.com/q/45135/23643

Answer (score 1):

1. The easiest way is to combine them into a single `.so` file by either combining all object files, or building two static `.a` libraries and then linking them into a single shared library.
2. If you really want to keep two `.so` files, link the first library to the second, as you would with executable. E.g. if `libfoo` depends on `libbar`, compile `libfoo` with `-lbar`. You'd have to have the dependent libraries in your default library path or in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "You'd have to have the dependent libraries in your default library path or in LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable" I don't want that, I want to completely remove all .so except only one of them and still be able to load it. As for your first suggestion, how can I combine all object files? Which parameters should I use to compile to object files?

Comment: @sinan How do you link two libraries that you already have? Take all files and put them in one command line.